# Unable to install numpy and pandas in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, ubuntu-18.04

I already tried

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools`
- `sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy`
- `sudo apt-get install libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base`

It was showing `Unable to locate package libatlas3gf-base`
So I tried

- `pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn`

But it failed. Failure is in the image as shown in this drive link "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_YZlQYpP5aGGbbEDKzIzsYeiEVIgEmGe".

Comment: Look at using Anaconda or Miniconda.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing with `pip`

- `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
- `sudo pip install pandas` or `sudo pip3 install pandas`
- `sudo pip install numpy` or `sudo pip3 install numpy`

Try also using a virtual enviroment just in case

`apt-get install python-virtualenv`
`virtualenv testVirtualEnv`
`cd testVirtualEnv`
`source bin/activate`
Now install dependencies

Virtual enviroments are also a good way of making projects in a more managable way

Comment: I used "sudo apt-get install python3-numpy" just now and it worked. Now I can use numpy and pandas. Thank you. could you please also explain why "Unable to locate package libatlas3gf-base" is showing up?

Comment: If that is showing up when running the program, probably the instalation did not went well. Try isolating with a virtualenv, ill update the answer